# Access denied on 1&1 server

Tags: .htaccess, upload, hosting, http-status-code-404

I am having a problem with hosting a website on a 1&1 server (Bought package is SmartWeb M). I uploaded everything to the public_html folder (before you ask - yes, index.html is located in the document root and not one of the subfolders). When I then try to call the page in a browser I get the following error:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Since I couldn't find any .htaccess on forehand I created one in hope that that would fix it - nothing.
I have been waiting for an answer from the 1&1 help desk in more than 3 days now and I am moderately angry at their service.

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, that my files did have the wrong permissions. Make sure to get them to -755!